# Not receiving the API call output from a fetch function in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, rest, node-fetch

I want to retrieve data from a API call and send the results to the user in NodeJS. There are separate functions for the API call and for the route call. The data is print to the console within the API call function, but not been sent to the route call. Please be kind to help me up with this. The API needs Basic auth headers.

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser  from'body-parser';
import  fetch from 'node-fetch';

// This server is used to get the issues of the project and store them in an array

/* App config */
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

/* Middleware */
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var issues = []
var issueIds = []

async function getIssueIds()
{  
  try
  {
    const response = await fetch('API link',
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: 
      {
        'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(
          'authorization data'
      ).toString('base64')}`,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        issues = json.issues;       
        for(let i = 0; i < issues.length; i++)
        {
            issueIds.push(issues[i].id)
        }
        return issueIds;
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        return data;
      })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    return err;
  }
}

app.get('/api/issues', (req, res) => 
{
    getIssueIds().then(issues => {
        console.log("Issue array: "+ issues);
    });

    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    
    //If success, send the data
    res.status(200).send(issueIds);
});

/* Listen */
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port : ${port}`));
```

Comment: You need to `return response;` in `getIssueIds` function.

Comment: Then it pops put "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'response' before initialization". Please note that I'm very new to NodeJS.

Comment: Where did you place the `return response;` You should place it just bellow `.catch(err => console.error(err));`

Comment: Now it's working, Thank you very much @Molda